# For no reason I can see I'm getting bad gateway

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-location

I'm fairly new to nginx, which I've heard a number of people raving about.

I'm running it on a DigitalOcean instance along with Node.JS, Mongo, Express and Angular.

I've recently added an SSL and it was initially working find. But when I went back a few days later, I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway.

My config is Really simple:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain_com/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain_com/mydomain.com.key;

#  side note: only use TLS since SSLv2 and SSLv3 have had recent vulnerabilities
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://130.78.19.81:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this?????

This is my Express App.js file. When I comment out the reference to bcrypt, everything works. Well, except the bcrypt methods. So I know this has something to do with it:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Thanks to http://blog.matoski.com/articles/jwt-express-node-mongoose/

// set up a mongoose model
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(passw, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(passw, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Seems most likely that the server at `http://130.78.19.81` is blocking port 3000 or possibly even the source IP using firewall restrictions.

Comment: I ran the following command and don't see the port open, but my understanding is that it should be:deploy@OM:~$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1116/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      919/mongod      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1116/sshd

Comment: It's not clear from your original post what your architecture is.  Is the node app running on the same machine as NGINX? where are  you running  your netstat command?